# Debouncing not working

Tags: javascript, debouncing

See http://jsfiddle.net/5MvnA/2/ and console.

There should be less Fs than Ks but there are no Fs at all.

I got the debouncing code

```
function debounce(fn, delay) {
  var timer = null;
  return function () {
    var context = this, args = arguments;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
      fn.apply(context, args);
    }, delay);
  };
}
```

from here http://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls/

Mind checking if I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: You are never calling the function! And the timer variable is not doing what you think.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code should look like this

```
$('input').keyup( function() {
    console.log('k');
});

$('input').keyup(debounce(f, 100));
```

In your example, you are never calling the function returned and it is always making a new function.

---

Based on your comment. How to use it in a different context. The following example will write `foo` 10 times to the console, but will only add one timestamp.

```
function debounce(fn, delay) {
  var timer = null;
  return function () {
    var context = this, args = arguments;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
      fn.apply(context, args);
    }, delay);
  };
}

function fnc () {
    console.log("Date: ",new Date());
}
var myDebouncedFunction = debounce(fnc, 100);

function foo() {
    console.log("called foo");
    myDebouncedFunction(); 
}

for ( var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    foo();
}
```

Comment: I get it. What if I want to use it not with events? Like at teh end of another function? How should I rewrite the debounce function? or is that not possible?

Comment: So: _.debounce returns a function but does not execute it. You must call _.debounce only once. If you want to call your debounced function multiple times, you must store the _.debounce wrapped version of the function and call this stored version. (these were the lessons I learned from this answer that helped me)

Answer (score 0):

You have to call function , returns from `debounce` . change code to

```
$('input').keyup( function() {
    console.log('k');
    this.func = this.func || debounce(f, 100);
    this.func.apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) ); 
});
```

Comment: F still gets called the same number of times as K, after K. So no debouncing. But this is interesting.